# Why does the Debian Lenny git package not install git?

Tags: git, debian-lenny

If I run the following command on Debian Lenny:

```
apt-get install git
```

... I'm unable to use git:

```
# git --version
bash: git: command not found
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The package you most likely want is **git-core**.

(Works just fine without adding an extra repository.)

*Update:* This has now been fixed; in squeeze and beyond [the git package is now called **git**](http://lists.debian.org/debian-devel/2009/09/msg00661.html).

Comment: Aha, that's a much easier approach. Thanks. I'm surprised that the Debian site didn't make this more clear. Oh well, that's Debian for you I guess.

Comment: However, with this approach you only get git version 1.5.6.5

Comment: Yes, that seems to be the version of the dvcs git being provided in lenny. So if you really need/want a newer version, there is still a benefit in going for the backports.

Comment: Will still mark yours as the valid answer, since it's less complicated! ;-)

Answer (score 5):

**To get ~1.7.1 use this method. If you want ~1.5.6.5 then use andol's answer.**

This is because `git` is a dummy package in Lenny which provides gnuit.

- [Package: git (4.9.4-1)](http://packages.debian.org/lenny/git)

However, you can get around this by using the [lenny-backports git package](http://packages.debian.org/lenny-backports/git):

**UPDATE: As of September 5th 2010, this method has changed slightly as backports.org is being phased out the instructions now follow the [recommended solution](http://wiki.debian.org/Backports) to install from the latest Debian backports.**

1. Add this line:

   ```
   deb http://archive.debian.org/debian-backports/ lenny-backports main contrib non-free
   ```

   to your /etc/apt/sources.list.
2. Run: `apt-get update`.
   If you get get a security warning about NO_PUBKEY AED4B06F473041FA, run step 3, 4 and 5 -- if not, skip to step 6.

   Run: `gpg --keyserver pgp.mit.edu --recv-keys AED4B06F473041FA`

   Run: `gpg --armor --export AED4B06F473041FA| apt-key add -`

   Run: `apt-get update` again to confirm.

   *Note, adding the debian-backport-keyring is no longer necessary.*
3. Run: `apt-get -t lenny-backports install git`
4. Run: `git --version`

   ```
   git version 1.7.2.3
   ```

Comment: When executing the 2nd gpg line, I got "gpg: can't open `/etc/apt/trusted.gpg'" and then an error.  I fixed this by su'ing instead of sudo'ing.  Then apt-get -t lenny-backports install git persists in claiming that 1.5.6.5 is the latest version of git.  I fixed this by replacing your recommended sources.list line with deb http://archive.debian.org/debian-backports lenny-backports main contrib non-free.  Then all was well.  Don't want to edit your answer, because I don't actually know what I'm doing.  Just thought I'd share what worked for me.